# Ionic v1 Add non-tabbed pages

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am writing to you because, after so many hours of research, I don't know how I can add new pages in my application.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH3Sg.png)

In fact I would like to click on a link (screenshot) in order to go on an other page..

Could you give me some indications pls ?
Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your app.js file

> .state('page1', {
>               url: '/page1',
>               templateUrl: 'app/page1/page1.html',
>               controller: 'page1Ctrl'
>           })

Answer (score 0):

main page (for example: home.html)

```
<a ng-click="orderlist()" />
```

homecontroller.js

```
$rootScope.orderlist= function()
{   
    $state.go('orderlist');
}
```

App.js

```
.state('orderlist', {
    url: '/orderlist',
        templateUrl: 'templates/orderlist/orderlist.html',
        controller: 'orderlistCtrl'
  })
```